# citrix session prompts for credentials

Tags: remote-desktop, credentials, citrix, citrix-receiver

In the 7.6 environment, opening an application from storefront in Chrome works, however opening it in Internet Explorer prompts for windows logon.
I'm using single sign on on Citrix receiver.
I don't understand why doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of IE specific issues:

> The Group Policy template includes support for configuring the system for in-session certificates. This places certificates in the user’s personal certificate store after logon for application use. For example, if you require TLS authentication to web servers within the VDA session, the certificate can be used by Internet Explorer. By default, VDAs will not allow access to certificates after logon.
>
> If you are using Internet Explorer, click Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab and clear the option “Do not save encrypted data to disk.”. This option should be cleared because the dynamic files are stored in the Temporary Internet Files folder. When applications are clicked, a file is downloaded to the folder, then launched using MIME type. If access to the folder is disabled or not available, the process cannot occur successfully.

Chrome and IE differ in how they manage redirects, and single sign-on relies on redirects:

> Internet Explorer 11: The VDA-side IE11 browser viewport is redirected and rendered on the client-side using the client-side installed IE11 and the Citrix Workspace app for Windows process HdxBrowser.exe.
>
> Google Chrome: The VDA-side Chrome browser viewport is redirected and rendered on the client-side using the Citrix Workspace app for Windows embedded Chrome engine and the HdxBrowserCef.exe process. Note that the Browser Content Redirection Extension must be installed and enabled on the VDA before using BCR with Chrome. The Browser Content Redirection Extension is available from the Chrome Web Store.

**References**

- [Federated Authentication Service](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-15-ltsr/secure/federated-authentication-service.html)
- [Federated Authentication Service architectures overview](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-15-ltsr/secure/federated-authentication-service/fas-architectures.html)
- [How to Troubleshoot Browser Content Redirection](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX230052)
- [Users Prompted to Download, Run, Open Launch.ica File, Instead of Launching Connection](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX804493)
- [Configure and install using command-line parameters](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/windows/current-release/install/cfg-command-line.html)
- [Elevation level and wfcrun32.exe](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/windows/current-release/secure-communication/wfcrun32-and-elevation-level.html)